# installation of Postgressql 12 fails on ubuntu - apt update has error

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

I'm trying to install postgres 12 on my ubuntu running machine, but I'm getting the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-12
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-client-12
```

Upon checking my logs I came to know that my `apt-update` has some errors.

```
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/chris-lea/redis-server/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                                 
Hit:2 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                                                  
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu cosmic InRelease                                                                             
Hit:4 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-updates InRelease                                                                          
Get:5 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease [3,959 B]                                                                
Hit:6 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu eoan InRelease                                                                                 
Hit:7 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-backports InRelease                                               
Hit:8 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic-security InRelease                          
Get:9 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages [175 kB]           
Err:9 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable/main amd64 Packages                         
  File has unexpected size (174890 != 175466). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 13.79.173.94 80]
  Hashes of expected file:
   - Filesize:175466 [weak]
   - SHA512:70328a95854c961a1e654955375672dd289df291e75fde88b2c4b057ac70971625a1e3a763c60fc412488cc3f8777054df1e63d12828a6e2e18e0d2c05b015de
   - SHA256:4519575aca57b07ff96b549ab46261c06fc5305760ce27024944cb4b4038fc20
   - SHA1:b70a3a16ddc97bed6311e0edaa2e9c2412a262b0 [weak]
   - MD5Sum:c5fca36709dc404c8abd2b3f84085587 [weak]
  Release file created at: Thu, 30 Apr 2020 07:17:55 +0000
Hit:10 https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk InRelease                                    
Ign:11 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt cosmic-pgdg InRelease
Err:12 http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt cosmic-pgdg Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 217.196.149.55 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list:2
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list:1 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google-cloud-sdk.list:2
```

I was facing similar issues while installing php but they were resolved once I made changes in `sources.list` to add `old-release.ubuntu`. Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated . I'm stuck for hours

Comment: Ubuntu cosmic (18.10) reached EOL in July 2019; PG 12 was not released until October. There will not be a postgresql-12 package available for that version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've updated my Ubuntu to 19.04 disco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future readers, as mentioned in the comments:

> Ubuntu cosmic (18.10) reached EOL in July 2019; PG 12 was not released until October. There will not be a postgresql-12 package available for that version of Ubuntu — [AdamKG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16361/adamkg)

Update your Ubuntu to at least 19.04.